# Unable to network-bootstrap using enterprise 3.2 version, due to 73 outstanding database changes

Tags: corda

I am using enterprise version 3.2 of network bootstrapper to build node configurations with devMode enabled. **When i bootstrap with default database backend (h2), it works fine.**

But when I am connecting to MSSQL DB backend, it fails to generate the node config with the following **error**.

**"There are 73 outstanding database changes that need to be run. Please use the advanced migration tool. See: https://docs.corda.r3.com/database-management.html"**

I do not have any apps placed in the directory during my bootstrapping process.
The database is a new one and there are no tables created yet. Yet, it is complaining about the database changes.

The link mentioned in the error, recommends us to do a database migration, specific to a cordapp. But in my case, i do not even have a cordapp.

How can I overcome this issue?

Here is the config file i used:

```
myLegalName="O=Branch,L=Bangalore,C=IN"
p2pAddress="192.168.100.104:11121"
devMode=true
rpcSettings {
    address="192.168.100.104:10011"
    adminAddress="192.168.100.104:11252"
}
rpcUsers=[
    {
        password=test
        permissions=[
            ALL
        ]
        user=user1
    }
]
dataSourceProperties = {
    dataSourceClassName = "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDataSource"
    dataSource.url = "jdbc:sqlserver://192.168.100.116:1433;databaseName=cordadb"
    dataSource.user = "adminuser"
    dataSource.password = "Password123"
}
database = {
    transactionIsolationLevel = READ_COMMITTED
}
jarDirs = ["/root/jdbcdriver/sqljdbc_6.2/enu/"]
```

Here is the command line that was invoked:

```
java -jar corda-tools-network-bootstrapper-3.2.jar --dir finance
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "73 outstanding database changes" referenced in the error message are the creation of the new database tables required by every Corda node.

You can run these automatically by adding `database.runMigration=true` to your node's `node.conf` file.